# iphone Album Covers randomly come up imusic app when trying to play music

Tags: iphone, music

I have playlist on my iphone 5c saved in imusic (imported from itunes).  Right in the middle of an important presentation, without touching anything, the screen went to a checkerboard of album covers, and no matter how I scrolled or what I did this screen would not leave and I did not have access to use my playlist (which I had up and ready to go).  The presentation music had to be played at very exact times. It had worked fine before. Very frustrating.  Not sure what and why this happened.  Anyone have suggestions to avoid this happening again?

Answer (score 1):

Landscape in the iOS Music app will show the grid view of your music.
To exit, **rotate your device to portrait**.

Comment: several album icons that have nothing to do with the current file I'm trying to play come up.